# C++ - Base class and private header

Tags: c++, static-libraries, header-files

I'm writing a library in C++ and have a class hierarchy like this:

message.h file (in ./mylib/src)

```
class Message
{
};
```

request.h file (in ./mylib/include/mylib)

```
#include "message.h"

class Request : public Message
{
};
```

response.h file (in ./mylib/include/mylib)

```
#include "message.h"

class Response : public Message
{
};
```

I want everything in my mylib/src folder to be hidden from user and want only to distrubute files in mylib/include.  But the problem is as both requst.h and response.h #include message.h so user will get a "No such file" error when #including request.h and response.h.  Is there a way to work around this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply provide a public interface for `Message` and keep the actual class hidden:

```
class IMessage
{
    Message* pImpl;
};
```

Distribute this header and use a forward declaration for `Message`.

Another option would be to use composition instead of inheritance (you'll need pointers as members, not the full object).

Comment: More info on pimpl: http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_100/ and http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_101/

Comment: Thanks.  I'd go for the second option.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to be able to use `Response` and `Request` you need to include the header files where they are declared. That is why you should put those headers in the public include folder.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Ideally I'd like to distribute only one header file (say "mylib.h") and allow user to use both Request and Response by #including this header file.  Is this possible?  If so, what would mylib.h contain?

Answer (score 0):

The base class should be publically distributed, or else you will have to write serialization / deserialization mecanisms.